# Correct mapping of big Visual FoxPro CHAR column to the appropriate SQL Server data type

Tags: sql-server, foxpro, sqldatatypes, visual-foxpro

I am migrating a Visual FoxPro database to SQL Server. One of the tables has a `Char` column with length `2147483647`. I am wondering if the correct data type to use in SQL Server 2008 R2 is `Char(2147483647)`. Is there an alternative type I can use in SQL Server which will not result in any loss of information?

The following image gives a description of the column as shown within Visual Studio 2008.

[image: Visual FoxPro Char column properties]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual FoxPro's native `CHAR` type only allows up to about 255 characters.  What you're seeing is a FoxPro [MEMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ww305zh2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) field, translated to a generic OLE equivalent.

A SQL Server [VARCHAR(MAX)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) is the usual proper equivalent, assuming the MEMO is simply user-entered text in a western dialect and not a multi-linqual or data-blob variation.

Be aware that FoxPro does NOT speak UTF natively, so you may have code-page translation issues.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone else.

[MSDN varchar description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) states:

> Use varchar(max) when the sizes of the column data entries vary considerably, and the size might exceed 8,000 bytes.

The maximum storage for `Char` is 8000 bytes/characters. `varchar(max)` on the other hand will use a storage size equal to the actual length of the characters entered plus 2 bytes.

Comment: If you have recommendations for an even more suitable data type, please share